# Generate all list of a given length between two values (OCaml or other languages)

Tags: ocaml

I am new to ocaml and trying to write some code to generate all lists of number between two value.

For example, if I call this function `generate`, I want to obtain something like this :

```
let generate ~min ~max ~length (* Maybe other arguments *) =
    (* The code *)
;;

generate ~min:0 ~max:3 ~length:4;;
```

Should return

```
[
[0;0;0];
[1;0;0];
[2;0;0];
[3;0;0];
[0;1;0];
```

And so on, to

```
[3;2;3];
[0;3;3];
[1;3;3];
[2;3;3];
[3;3;3];
]
```

I already tried code like this :

```
open Core.Std;;

type next_list =
    | Complete of int list
    | Partial of int list
    | Result of (int array) list
;;

let rec next ~r ~min ~max ~l =
    let detox = function | Partial a -> a | _ -> assert false in
    match l with
    | Partial (hd :: tl) when hd <= max -> Partial (hd + 1 :: tl)
    | Partial (hd :: tl) when hd = max + 1 -> next ~r ~min ~max
    ~l:(Partial (min :: (detox (next ~r ~min ~max ~l:(Partial tl))) ))
    | Complete (hd :: tl) when hd <= max -> next ~r:([l] :: r) ~min ~max
    ~l:(Complete (hd + 1 :: tl))
    | Complete (hd :: tl) when hd = max + 1 -> next ~r ~min ~max
    ~l:(Complete (min :: (detox (next ~r ~min ~max ~l:(Partial tl)))))
    (*| Partial [] -> next ~r ~min ~max ~l:(Result r)*)
    | Result a -> Result a
```

It may be spread around several functions if necessary, that is not a problem.
I am also interested by non ocaml code or idea.

Thanks for your help.

This is my first question on Stackoverflow, do not hesitate to say if my question is unclear.

Comment: I tried several recursive function increasing head to the max and then append the next list, taking from the tail.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13998275/generate-all-lists-of-size-n-such-that-each-element-is-between-0-and-m-inclusi/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here some solution :
First, let's define that takes 2 lists l1 & l2 as input and that produces a list of list, where each element is l2 augmented by 1 element of l1 :

```
 let enumerate l ll = List.fold ~init:[] ~f:(fun op x -> (x::ll)::op) l;;
```

enumerate [0;1;2;3] [4;5;6];;
- : int list list = [[3; 4; 5; 6]; [2; 4; 5; 6]; [1; 4; 5; 6]; [0; 4; 5; 6]]

Now generate :

```
   let rec generate length ll =
     if length=1 then List.fold ~init:[] ~f:(fun op x -> [x]::op) ll
     else 
       let result = generate (length-1) ll in
       List.fold ~init:[] ~f:(fun op x -> (enumerate ll x)@op) result;;
```

and usage is as follows :

```
generate 2 [1;2;3];; (* instead of generate ~min:1 ~max:3 ~length:2 *)
```

Some explanation :
List.fold ~init:[] ~f:(fun op x -> [x]::op) ll 
=> this creates the initial list of list (singleton)

And the second : takes each of the list of length -1 and performs the enumeration.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a hint:

```
let count_prefix low high lists =
  ???

let generate min max length =
  let rec recur low high len =
    if len = 0 then []
    else count_prefix low high (recur low high (len - 1)) in
  recur min max length
```

`count_prefix` should return a list that is the elements of `lists` prefixed with the numbers `low` to `high`. If `lists` is empty, it should return a list of lists containing the numbers `low` to `high`. That is:

```
count_prefix 0 3 [] => [[0]; [1]; [2]]
count_prefix 0 3 [[10];[20]] => [[0; 10]; [0; 20]; [1; 10]; [1; 20]; [2; 10]; [2; 20]]
```

Fill in the definition of `count_prefix`.